# Is there any tool for windows emulating functionality of command-T plugin for vim?

Tags: vim, productivity

As in the title. It would be usefull to have, for example, a tool like Executor or launchy, but with command-T fuzzy matching.

Comment: Doesn't Launchy (and, AFAIK, all the others) already use fuzzy matching? That's why you get `free our okapis.ppt` and `foo.c` when you type `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about using it with Vim for Windows? If so, Command-T works there too. Another plugin that works is [Ctrl-P](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736).

Comment: When I wrote that, I had forgotten Command-T requires Ruby and DevKit; so there are some additional hurdles on Windows.

Comment: ctrl-p also doesn't require vim to be compiled with ruby/py flags which makes it better for the default OS X implemented Vim/Windows